Induced isomorphisms in rigid tensor categories.
This question is inspired by this question Tensor functors in rigid tensor categories.
In the answer there, we are given a claimed proof (I have not understood it) of why tensor functors between rigid tensor categories, are such that they induce isomorphisms $F_{X,Y}:F(\underline{\text{Hom}}(X,Y)) \to \underline{\text{Hom}}(FX,FY)$ coming from the tensor-hom adjunction with respect to internal-hom.
Now, in both Catégories tannakiennes (proposition 5.2.2,I) and Tannakian Categories we are given no such proof, instead, they basically use the same argument, more developed in "Catégories tannakiennes", that $F_{X,\mathbf{1}} := F_{X}:F(X^{\vee}) \to \underline{\text{Hom}}(FX,F\mathbf{1}) \cong F(X)^{\vee}$ is an isomorphism.
A question about the exact same subject has been answered here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/454157/tensor-functor-between-rigid-tensor-categories-preserves-texthom-objects/454160#454160
But possibly due to my inexperience, I failed to understand the answers given in the link above, and felt they lacked the details someone without much experience would understand (bachelor student). I know how to show that $F$ preserves dual objects. The argument from "Catégories tannakiennes" claims to give a proof that $F_{X}$ is an isomorphism. Now, assume we know all of this. Is it obvious from the fact that if all $F_{X}$ are isomorphisms, it follows that maps $F_{X,Y}$ are isomorphisms? It is obvious, if one knows that diagram 4.3.3.2,I in Catégories Tannakiennes commutes, but then one is still left with showing that said diagram commutes, for which the book gives no proof, from what I can tell.
